# ROS Answers SE migration: markers python

Tags: ros, python, markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I need to add in rviz a marker from a python code. The thing is that I have a ekf map based localization written in python and it is using matplotlib, but I want to plot everithing on rviz, so I need to use markers. All the turtorials I've found are in cpp, but I am obviously not going to change all the code from python to cpp for this.

Where can I find something on python and markers?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33423/markers-python/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2012-05-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Marker messages are ROS messages just like anything else you can publish from a python node, there's nothing special about them. You can find an example in [this question/answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/11135/plotting-a-markerarray-of-spheres-with-rviz).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4